# if image click i want to redirect the another page

Tags: php, html

i have slider image list. this list image has id. if id become equel to some specific number like 24(this is the image that i want to move another page after click the image)

code

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from ".$tblImages." Where cid=1 Order by image_order";
$rs  = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$i=0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $autoid = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $sub_title = $row['sub_title'];
    $textarea_top = $row['textarea_top'];
    $textarea_width = $row['textarea_width'];
    $images = $row['images'];
    $image_order = $row['image_order'];
    if($textarea_top !=''){
        $_top =' top:'.$textarea_top.'px;'; 
    }else{$_top ='';}
    if($textarea_width !=''){
        $_width =' width:'.$textarea_width.'px;';   
    }else{$_width ='';}
        echo "if ($autoid == 24) 
             { 
               <a href ="fund.html"> </a> "  
              /*this is the image  become appear in a wall you click
              and have to go another page like fund.html */
             } ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
if ($autoid == 24) 
{ 
  echo "<a href ='fund.html'><img src='your/img/path/here'/></a>";
}
```

You can use JavaScript to do the trick for you:

```
if ($autoid == 24){
  echo "<li id='feature-6' class='feature_thumb' onclick='window.location=\"fund.html\"'>
           <a href='assets/home/slider_5.jpg'>
                <div class='textArea slide_7' style='top:365px; width:600px;'>
                      <h1>Effective Fundraising</h1>
                      <p>the Eternal Struggle of NGO's Countered</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>";
}
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: then do i need to write the code     $(document).ready(function(){ $("#id").show(); }); is this correct

Comment: When looking at your code, I think you don't need that. Have you tried the code already?

Comment: yes i tries but this is appearing the image page loading time but i need slider is rotating once that special image is appear into the page if user want to get more details user can click and redirect to the fund.html page this is the what i want

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then that's exactly what my code is doing. When the user clicks on the image, they will be redirected to the page fund.html. Do you want to have the ID of the clicked image on the fund.html page?

Comment: no i dont need id. only the image is appear on the page.once user want to get more details then click the image and goes to fund.html

Comment: Isn't that what my code is doing? I will explain my code:
If the ID is equal to 24 then echo an image. If the user clicks on the image, the site will redirect the user to fund.html.
What happens when you click on the image?

Comment: ok its like this. i have image slider 1,2,3,4,5 each image has id. image1 has id =19,image2 id =20 and etc. once image5 appear it has the id.that id assign to the $autoit variable.these images rotating(sliding) once image5 is appear user need more info click the image and go to fund.html page.                          but ur code is like this once the index.html page load image5.jpg is loading and not rotating until uuser click

Comment: So you want the page to automatically redirect to fund.html?

Comment: no once if that relevant add(image appear) user like to read more then user has to click the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74913/discussion-between-michel-and-nuke-infer).

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
<a href ="fund.html"> </a> "
```

you can use

```
header("Location: /index.php");
```

or

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     window.location = url;
</script>';
```

Comment: if ($autoid == 24){
                                  header("Location: /fund.html");
                        }  /* i tried this it is not redirecting the the page */

Comment: what error is showing....? header("Location: /fund.html");  does path to fund.html is correct? maybe try "Location: ./fund.html" .. Add a dot(.) in front of /

Comment: try the second one where url = './fund.html'.

Comment: if ($autoid ==24){        
                              echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = './fund.html';
      </script>';
                            }
                                              this is getting wrong